# What are the expression syntax over types C++ support?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I was working with a templated class which takes a set of integers. The code was like,

```
template<unsigned... Idx>
struct work{ ... };
```

Then I realized, user may need to provide either a set of integers, or a range of integers. So, I changed the syntax little to support instantiation like,

```
work<indexes<1,3,2,4> > //instead of work<1,3,2,4>
work<span<1,4> > //same as work<1,2,3,4>
```

While, in C++ we have large number of operators, and can be used to formulate exotic expression templates (say `boost::xpressive`, `boost::lambda`, `boost::spirit` etc) , possibilities for type manipulation is much less.

In a boostcon keynote by Sean Parent, he noted one still can not write `pair<int>` to denote `a pair of integers`. In my persinal library, I made a syntax like `tuple<int[3]>` to denote a tuple of 3 integers, instead of writing a tuple with 3 int in the type arguments, noting that I do not write a raw array as tuple argument anywhere! (note: `std::array<int,3>` is not same as the above, as std::array can not store references while `tuple` can, say `std::tuple<int&,int&,int&>` is possible)

So, I want to know what are the different kind of "type expressions" I can write?

So far I can think of object type, function type, reference type, with/without cv modifiers, pointers etc. e.g

```
    template<class T>
    struct tpl;

    using t1 = tpl<int>;//simple type
    //function (can have function pointer/reference also) 
    // e.g. void(*)(int,float) or void(&)(int,float)
    using t2 = tpl<void(int,float)>;
    //array can have pointer / reference also
    //e.g. int(&)[4] or int (*)[4]
    using t3 = tpl<int[4]>;
    using t4 = tpl<int[]>;
    using t5 = tpl<int const>;//with cv modifiers
    using t6 = tpl<int*>;//with pointer
    using t7 = tpl<int&>;//with reference (& or &&)
    using t8 = tpl<tpl<int> >; //template itself
    using t9 = tpl<void(...)>; //variadic functions
    using t10 = tpl<R C::*>; //pointer to member
```

But I believe, many more are possible.

NOTE: This question is purely theoretical, **I just want to know all kinds of syntax I can write inside <> as type argument**, and not about the readability/morality aspect of it, or even how can I implement some of the examples I had given, like the work class.

Comment: There is an infinity of answers to this question, for example the infinite series `char, char*, char**, ...`. It cannot therefore be answered in a finite way.

Comment: Yes, yes, I know! But if they are regular, I can still express them as  `a type followed by zero or more *`, or any other way, as long as it expresses the intent.

Comment: Look for `type_id` in the standard.

Comment: @EJP A lot of infinite things can be expressed in a finite way.

Comment: @abir pardon the misunderstanding, then. Perhaps the sample could have been omitted/put at the end. Also, "How much *** can we have" is probably not the best fit for an SO question

Comment: @EJP Try "Any type `T` with one or more layers of pointer indirection, e.g., `char*, char**, char***, ...`." I'd say that sentence is finite. :)

Comment: Unsure why this has 4 close votes. There's an explicit part in the standard which covers this exact question, which means WG21 considered a question worth addressing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Compound types can be constructed using the declarator syntax - found in `[dcl.decl]`.

Underlying this syntax are six fundamental constructs, within which any `T` can be substituted by any of the other constructs in the list. [In the following, `(T)` represents a list of zero or more types (which may end in '...'), and `<T>` represents a list of one or more types.]

```
T // T
T* // pointer to T
T& // reference to T
T[n] // array of size 'n' of T
T C::* // pointer to C::member of type T
T (T) // function taking '(T)' and returning T
```

**EDIT**: The type of a class template specialization can be subsituted for any `T`:

```
C<T> // specialization of class template C with arguments '<T>'
```

There are combinations of the above that produce constructs which have special significance:

```
T (*)(T) // pointer to function taking '(T)' and returning T
T (C::*)(T) // pointer to C::member-function taking '(T)' and returning T
```

Additionally, some of the constructs may be cv-qualified:

```
const T // const T
T* const // const pointer to T
T C::* const // const pointer to C::member of type T
```

Not all of the combinations result in valid types. According to `[basic.compound]`, only the following combinations can be used:

> Compound types can be constructed in the following ways:
>
> - arrays of objects of a given type
> - functions, which have parameters of given types and return void or references or objects of a given type
> - pointers to void or objects or functions (including static members of classes) of a given type
> - references to objects or functions of a given type
> - pointers to non-static class members, which identify members of a given type within objects of a given class

Additional restrictions are mentioned:

> `[dcl.ptr]` there are no pointers to references
>
> `[dcl.ref]` There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and no pointers to references
>
> `[dcl.mptr]` A pointer to member shall not point to ... a member with reference type, or
>   "cv void."
>
> `[dcl.fct]` The parameter list (void) is equivalent to the empty parameter list. Except for this special case, void shall not be a parameter type. ... If the type of a parameter includes a type of the form “pointer to array of unknown bound of T” or “reference
>   to array of unknown bound of T,” the program is ill-formed. Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function.

Some of the possible constructs **cannot** be used as template-arguments. When you explicitly specify a set of template-arguments, the compiler must check that the template-arguments can be substituted for the template-parameters without resulting in an 'invalid type'. According to `[temp.deduct]\2`, the following constructs constitute invalid types:

> Type deduction may fail for the following reasons:
>
> - Attempting to create an array with an element type that is void, a function type, or a reference type, or attempting to create an array with a size that is zero or negative.
>
>   ```
>   template <class T> int f(T[5]);
>   int I = f<int>(0);
>   int j = f<void>(0); // invalid array
>   ```
> - Attempting to use a type that is not a class type in a qualified name.
>
>   ```
>   template <class T> int f(typename T::B*);
>   int i = f<int>(0);
>   ```
> - Attempting to use a type in the qualifier portion of a qualified name that names a type  when that type does not contain the specified member, or if the specified member is not a type where a type is required.
>
>   ```
>   template <class T> int f(typename T::B*);
>   struct A {};
>   struct C { int B; };
>   int i = f<A>(0);
>   int j = f<C>(0);
>   ```
> - Attempting to create a pointer to reference type.
> - Attempting to create a reference to a reference type or a reference to void.
> - Attempting to create "pointer to member of T" when T is not a class type.
>
>   ```
>   template <class T> int f(int T::*);
>   int i = f<int>(0);
>   ```
> - Attempting to perform an invalid conversion in either a template argument expression, or an expression used in the function declaration.
>
>   ```
>   template <class T, T*> int f(int);
>   int i2 = f<int,1>(0); // can’t conv 1 to int*
>   ```
> - Attempting to create a function type in which a parameter has a type of void.
> - Attempting to create a cv-qualified function type.

**EDIT:** This is based on C++03, but also applies to C++11 (which adds rvalue reference types)

Comment: The others I know about are references like `T&` , `T&&`,`T(&)(A...)` array like `T[]`

Comment: The list actually misses templates themselves. That's relevant to the question: `using t8 = tpl<tpl<int>>;`

Comment: You are missing varargs functions. They are very distinct from variadic template functions, and both `T foo(U..., ...)` and `T foo(...)` are different from `T foo(U...)`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking about. I thought the sample you gave was interesting and played a little bit with it.

I came up with an implementation that makes `span<a,b>` to be a *template alias* for `indexes<a, ..., b>`, using the trick of type deduction in `constexpr` functions:

```
template <int a, int b> using span = decltype(expand_span<a,b>());
```

Now you can have your cake and eat it:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// using indirect template arguments
template<typename> struct indirect_work { };

void test_indirect()
{
    indirect_work<indexes<1,2,3,4>> x;
    indirect_work<span<1,4>>        y;

    x = y; // x and y are of identical types
    static_assert(std::is_same<indexes<1,2,3,4>, span<1,4>>::value, "fact check");
}
```

But, perhaps more interestingly, **you can still have your primary `work` template take a raw `<int...>`** template argument list:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// using direct template arguments
template<int...> struct direct_work { };

// deduction alias:
template<int... direct> constexpr direct_work<direct...> deduction_helper(indexes<direct...>);
template <typename Idx> using deduce = decltype(deduction_helper(Idx{}));

void test_direct()
{
    direct_work<1,2,3,4> x;
    deduce<indexes<1,2,3,4>> y;
    deduce<span<1,4>> z;

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x), decltype(y)>::value, "fact check");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x), decltype(z)>::value, "fact check");
}
```

See a complete working demonstration here: [gcc on ideone](http://ideone.com/U2geNF). I compiled it with clang locally.

---

#### Full code

Code for `expand_span` duplicated here in case link should go dead:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int...> struct indexes {};

namespace {
    template<int a, int... other>
        constexpr indexes<a, other...> combine(indexes<other...> deduce);

    template<int a, int b, typename Enable = void> struct expand_span_; // primary

    template<int a, int b>
    struct expand_span_<a, b, typename std::enable_if< (a==b), void >::type> {
        static constexpr indexes<a> dispatch();
    };

    template<int a, int b>
    struct expand_span_<a, b, typename std::enable_if< (a<b), void >::type> {
        static constexpr decltype(combine<a>(expand_span_<a+1, b>::dispatch())) 
            dispatch();
    };

    template<int a, int b>
    constexpr auto expand_span() -> decltype(expand_span_<a,b>::dispatch());
}

template <int a, int b> using span = decltype(expand_span<a,b>());

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// using indirect template arguments
template<typename> struct indirect_work { };

void test_indirect()
{
    indirect_work<indexes<1,2,3,4>> x;
    indirect_work<span<1,4>>        y;

    x = y; // x and y are of identical types
    static_assert(std::is_same<indexes<1,2,3,4>, span<1,4>>::value, "fact check");
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// using direct template arguments
template<int...> struct direct_work { };

// deduction alias:
template<int... direct> constexpr direct_work<direct...> deduction_helper(indexes<direct...>);
template <typename Idx> using deduce = decltype(deduction_helper(Idx{}));

void test_direct()
{
    direct_work<1,2,3,4> x;
    deduce<indexes<1,2,3,4>> y;
    deduce<span<1,4>> z;

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x), decltype(y)>::value, "fact check");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x), decltype(z)>::value, "fact check");
}

int main()
{
    test_indirect();
    test_direct();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for how to implement that `work` class. If you look at the question, I am asking what all I can put inside `<>` as template type argument. We have fairly clear idea about EDSL, but how much expressive things can we write as type argument?

Comment: PS. have you looked at ProtoV5 (https://github.com/ericniebler/proto-0x)? It uses function types extensively to mimic EDSLs in it's template arguments. E.g. [A First Look at Proto-0x](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JF6YM0XzHnE), e.g. `constexpr map_list_of_expr<terminal(map_list_of_)> map_list_of {};` on [slide 37](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2013)

Comment: Yes, I had noticed proto has those beautiful function types, the other intuitive syntax's are T[N] to say N times T (who uses raw array anymore!) , and T* to say zero or more T (again who uses native pointer?) . I do not know if c++14 object alias/expression alias will give something more beautiful like `tuple<3_times<T> >`

Comment: I agree `T[N]` has quite some expressive potential. (However I think using `tuple<T[N]>` to mean `tuple<T, T, ...>` violates the principle of least surprise in spectacular ways :)). Long story short, maybe you should take up Haskell or [Boo](http://www.manning.com/rahien/) :) (Or Factor, if concatenative languages don't deter you :))

Comment: There's of course the precedence of `std::function<void(int)>` not containing a `void(int)`.

Comment: @MSalters aherm. No kidding! You're saying there are other library classes that _also_ don't have surprising interfaces! Aha. Well, that's why you don't expect that `tuple<void(int)>` models a _unary calleable_ and you _do_ expect `std::add_reference<int[12]>` to describe an array reference type, but not `tuple<int[12]>` (anyways, \@abir: what's wrong with `tuple<int, 12>`? Cf. `array<int, 12>`)

Comment: @not-sehe Nothing wrong at all! But how can I say tuple<int,float> AND tuple<int,2> or even tuple<int&&,2,float&,3,bool,2> ? For functions, I can `overload`, but for class template how can I make an argument either type parameter or value parameter? And array<int,12> is different beast all together as array does not work with references. so array<int&,12> or array<int&&,12> does not work. Moreover, array is homogeneous, while tuple is heterogeneous.

Comment: Good point on the 'immobility' of the primary template (i.e. type/non-type congruency). The rest was pretty well known. I'm pretty confident I could expand my sample implementation to support `work<repeat<7, int>, float, repeat<0, std::string> >` and do what you expect. Would that be something you want (sadly, we can't have `repeat(7, int)` without preprocessor magic. Yet.)

Comment: @not-sehe That is what I exactly do. It is nearly same as the `work` example. If we use templates they looks very much like LISP. e.g. `and_<is_forward_iterator<Iter>,not_<is_nothrow_constructible<iterator_value<Iter> ,Args...> > ` . We can have `repeat(int_<7>, int)` also, but again prefix form. `work<int[7],float,std::string[1]>` is infix form, but not so clear (after all which DSL is clear? I had hard time to digest `&` as serialization operator for boost!). I was looking for all interesting things I can write in `<>` pair! C++ is funny!