# How does template converting operator to pointer to member function syntax work

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member, nullptr

I was looking at the [emulated version of nullptr](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf) and saw this converting operator (a member of nullptr_t):

```
template<class C, class T>    // or any type of null
operator T C::*() const       // member pointer...
{ return 0; }
```

This syntax for pointer to member function confuses me. I usually expect to see such a type as something like

```
R (C::*)(I1, I2, ...)
```

With the template above, there's no input arguments. I can't figure out how the type deduction works in this case. I'm having trouble forming a specific question, other than, how does this work? If I have code like this:

```
typedef int (MyClass::*MyTypedef)(float);
MyTypedef m = nullptr;
```

I'm guessing T deduces to int, and C deduces to MyClass. What "happens" to float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a *pointer to member*, not necessarily a *pointer to member **function***. The difference is that it can generate a pointer to member function or a pointer to non-function member.

Now in the particular use case, the destination is a pointer to member, the compiler is seeing an expression in which it needs a `int (MyClass::*)(float)`, and on the other hand it has a `nullptr`. It tries to find a conversion and it finds the `operator T C::*()`, which is a valid conversion if `C` is deduced to be `MyClass` and `T` is deduced to be `int (float)` [function taking a `float` and returning an `int`].

I also find this particular corner of the language a bit confusing (having typedefs, or deduced types for functions), for example this is legal if *weird*:

```
typedef void int_f(int);
struct X {
   int_f m;
};
void X::m(int x) { std::cout << x << '\n'; }
```

The same thing is going on in the conversion operator that you are concerned with.

Comment: If you parse the type into its component parts, the substitution makes more sense. `T C::* [pointer to member of class C of type [T]]` where `[T]` is substituted with `T(P) [function taking P and returning [T]]` results in `T (C::*)(P) [pointer to member of class C of type [function taking P and returning [T]]]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142130/what-are-the-expression-syntax-over-types-c-support/17147477#17147477