# Member function type for template specialization

Tags: c++, function, templates

I am studying the uses of function types in template specialization and I am wondering if there such a thing as a member function type (not talking about member function pointers).

The case that led me to this question is better explained by an exemple...

```
template< typename FunctionType >
struct Function; // Undefined

// Specialize for functions with 0 parameter...
template< typename ReturnType >
struct Function< ReturnType() > // Notice the unusual syntax here...
{
    // Function pointer that fits the signature of the template...
    ReturnType (*m_pointerToFunction)();
};

// Specialize for functions with 1 parameter...
template< typename ReturnType, typename ParameterType >
struct Function< ReturnType(ParameterType) >
{
    ReturnType (*m_pointerToFunction)(ParameterType);
};

// ... etc up to a certain number of parameter.

// To use this template:
void SomeFunctionTakingNoParameter()
{
}

Function< void() > test;
test.m_pointerToFunction = SomeFunctionTakingNoParameter;
```

Now what I would like to do is create specialization for member functions. The first thing I tried is:

```
template< typename ReturnType, typename ObjectType, typename ParameterType >
class Function< ObjectType, ReturnType(ParameterType) >
{
    ReturnType (ObjectType::*m_memberFunctionPointer)(ParameterType);
};
```

and I use it like this:

```
struct Object
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
    }
};
Function< Object, void() > function;
function.m_memberFunctionPointer = &Object::DoSomething;
```

I have to supply 2 arguments to the template (the object type and the signature). I would like to see if there is a way to do it all in one parameter.

The next bit does not compile but I wonder if there is something similar in the language?

```
template< typename ObjectType, typename ReturnType >
struct Function< ObjectType::ReturnType() >
{
    ReturnType (ObjectType::*m_memberFunctionPointer)();
};
Function< Object::void() > function;
function.m_memberFunctionPointer = &Object::DoSomething;
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `void(Object::*)()` defines a *pointer-to-member-function* type. There is no such thing as a *member-function* type in C++.

In theory you could obtain a *member-function* type with `std::remove_pointer<void(Object::*)()>::type`, but this is not valid C++. The documentation for [`boost::remove_pointer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/remove_pointer.html) makes a note of this.

The *pointer-to-member-function* type `T (C::*)()` is produced by combining a *function* type `T()` with a *pointer-to-member* type `T C::*`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142130/what-are-the-expression-syntax-over-types-c-support/17147477#17147477) for how this combination works.

You can perform this combination with a simple helper template:

```
template<typename C, typename T>
struct PointerToMember
{
    typedef T C::* Type;
};

typedef PointerToMember<Object, void()>::Type Type; // void(Object::*)()
```

This may be useful when extending `Function` to support pointer-to-member.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 there is [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/decltype), which can give you the type of an expression, e.g. `decltype ObjectType::DoSomething` in your case, rather than `ObjectType::ReturnType()`.  The old-school way of doing this is to require that `struct Object` contain a member type with a specific name, such as `ReturnType`, and you simply use `typename ObjectType::ReturnType` (without parentheses).

Answer (score -1):

"There is no such thing as a member-function type in C++."

I guess that pretty much answers my question. Thanks :)

Comment: You probably wanted to put this in a comment on my answer ;). I've also edited the answer to add some relevant information.